# Remove ids from Wordpress form and form elements

Tags: wordpress, forms

When i use this inside of the loop on my bloglist page:

```
<?php comment_form( array( 'post_id' => get_the_ID() ) ); ?>
```

I get a form for each post wich is exactly what I want.

My problem is that since the form itself and the input fields and textarea has ids, the page won't validate. I get errors for multiple ids naturally.

For example does all my forms have id="commentform"

How can I make Wordpress remove all ids in these forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass more options to the function see below. Replace `<INSERT-UNIQUE-VALUE>` with something unique or you can auto generate it with `php` for example `md5(time())`;

```
<?php 
// Specify options
$options = array(
    'id_form' => '<INSERT-UNIQUE-VALUE>',
    'id_submit' => '<INSERT-UNIQUE-VALUE>',
    'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="<INSERT-UNIQUE-VALUE>">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label><textarea id="<INSERT-UNIQUE-VALUE>" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>'
);

// output the form
comment_form($options, get_the_ID()); 
?>
```

For more references see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form#.24args

Comment: That looks like a great idéa. How do I change the ids on the divs, spans and text inputs that wordpress puts out, if I can do that, I'll be safe.

Comment: Check the reference link, there are all the options. There are no more ids to worry about.

Comment: It works great on the form, inputfields and the textarea, but I can't change the div and some spans that has id's. Thanks anyway, I'll mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: I's really dumb that wordpress throws in a bunch of id's in the comment form because it makes it really difficult to use multiple forms on the same page and not getting validation errors.

Answer (score -2):

You could solve this with jquery by replacing your ID with a new ID and adding a number to your ids so the form id's would be id="newId0", id="newId1", id="newId2 and so on. Then it will validate.

```
$('form').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("id","newId"+index);
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tdf3ah2/)

Comment: I thought about that earlier, but won't the validator read the html only, before any javaScript has rendered?

Comment: This will not solve the problem and this is considered a bad practice. Do not use such approach dealing with validator issues.

Comment: Could you expand upon why this is considered a bad practice? Are you saying the jquery solution is a bad practice for this particular problem, or it is always a bad practice? Is it a bad practice for adding to/replacing ids or classes as well? Just interested in your thoughts.